# How Would I create Two Sections, A header with two sections and a footer without using tables?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I created a layout like this using tables, but how would I do this using only CSS and div tags? I have been trying to search the web for the past hour, and have not gotten anywhere. Could anyone point me in the right direction? How would I start coding this?

I drew up a little example of what I am trying to accomplish.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Learn a little bit about [CSS layout](http://learnlayout.com/). This isn't very difficult, but people stopped using tables for layout years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this by nesting tables and then defining their size, etc. in the css.

That said, please remember:

> [Note: Tables should not be used for page layout! Historically, some Web authors have misused tables in HTML as a way to control their page layout. However, there are a variety of alternatives to using HTML tables for layout, primarily using CSS.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp)

In other words, this would be really bad practice unless it's for a class assignment.

Comment: I've did it with tables already, but I'm trying to figure out how to do it only using CSS with no tables.

Comment: @JoshBurkman Ahh, I see. You would not want to use tables/columns at all (you mention wanting to use columns in the question which is why you got the answers you did). 

Check out the header, section, and footer HTML tags; those are the containers you will want to use. You can apply your CSS formatting to those to achieve the layout you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use div elements. Use CSS to add width to achieve the desired layout.